# Testing with MEF and Moq and NUnit

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, moq, mef

Shown below are the class and the method in the test class. The test method is for testing during the state that a monitoring request is published. The expected action is that the handler is called inside the FzrteMonitoringService class.

Here, I am trying to verify whether the handler for the monitoringRequestGenerated event is called inside the FzrteMonitoringService class. But the problem is that the class Dependency is a dependency, and I trying to figure out how to write the FzrteMonitoringService class to avoid such a dependency. The Dependency class is a class that works with MEF to resolve instances exported with the Export attribute. An architect was responsible for its design. Replacing the Dependency class with a TestDependency class for tests seems like an idea, but how would it create instances?

```
        [ImportingConstructor]
        public FzrteMonitoringService(IEventAggregator inEventAggregator)
        {
            _eventAggregator = inEventAggregator;
            _monitoringRequestExecutor = Dependency.Resolve<IFzrteMonitoringRequestResponseHandler>();
            WatchedPorts = new List<string>();
            FailedAddWatchRequests = new List<MonitoringRequest>();
            _monitoringRequests = new ConcurrentQueue<FzrteMonitoringRequest>();

            //subsription for monitoring requests on the UI thread to limit the user
            //from generating meaningless requests
            _eventAggregator.GetEvent<MonitoringRequestGenerated>()
                .Subscribe(FilterEventType, ThreadOption.UIThread, true);

        }

        [Test]
        [Category("Simple Basic Tests")]
        public void SubscribesToMonitoringRequets_requestPublished_FilterEventTypeCalled()
        {
            //mock of event aggregator and the request event dependencies of monitoring service
            var mockEventAggregator = new Mock<IEventAggregator>();
            var mockMonitoringRequestedEvent = new Mock<MonitoringRequestGenerated>();

            mockEventAggregator.Setup(x => x.GetEvent<MonitoringRequestGenerated>())
                .Returns(mockMonitoringRequestedEvent.Object);

            Action <List<MonitoringRequest>> callbackMethod = null;

            mockMonitoringRequestedEvent.Setup(x => x.Subscribe(
                It.IsAny<Action<List<MonitoringRequest>>>(),
                It.IsAny<ThreadOption>(),
                It.IsAny<bool>(),
                It.IsAny<Predicate<List<MonitoringRequest>>>())).
                Callback<Action<List<MonitoringRequest>>,
                    ThreadOption,
                    bool,
                    Predicate<List<MonitoringRequest>>>((a, t, b, p) => callbackMethod = a);



            var testFzrteMonitoringService = new FzrteMonitoringService(mockEventAggregator.Object);

            //use the actual  event aggregator to publish

            var mockMonitoringRequestEventPayload = new Mock<List<MonitoringRequest>>();
            mockEventAggregator.Object.GetEvent<MonitoringRequestGenerated>().Publish(mockMonitoringRequestEventPayload.Object);

            mockMonitoringRequestedEvent.Verify(x => x.Subscribe(testFzrteMonitoringService.FilterEventType));


        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really clear what exactly you're trying to test, looking on a code you've provided, but I'll try to address your question.

The main problem with Dependency class is that it's static (or probably its Resolve<> method). You should try to abstract it via introducing IDependency interface

```
public interface IDependency
{
    T Resolve<T>();
}
```

so you can inject it into your service and then mock it in your tests.
After this simple refactoring your service's constructor will look like this:

```
[ImportingConstructor]
public FzrteMonitoringService(
        IEventAggregator inEventAggregator, 
        IDependency dependency)
{
    _eventAggregator = inEventAggregator;
    _dependency = dependency;

    _monitoringRequestExecutor = dependency.Resolve<IFzrteMonitoringRequestResponseHandler>();
    WatchedPorts = new List<string>();
    _monitoringRequests = new ConcurrentQueue<FzrteMonitoringRequest>();

    //subsription for monitoring requests on the UI thread to limit the user
    //from generating meaningless requests
    _eventAggregator.GetEvent<MonitoringRequestGenerated>()
        .Subscribe(this.FilterEventType, ThreadOption.UIThread, true);
}
```

and your test:

```
[Test]
[Category("Simple Basic Tests")]
public void SubscribesToMonitoringRequets_requestPublished_FilterEventTypeCalled()
{
    //mock of event aggregator and the request event dependencies of monitoring service
    var mockEventAggregator = new Mock<IEventAggregator>();
    var mockMonitoringRequestedEvent = new Mock<MonitoringRequestGenerated>();
    var mockDependecy = new Mock<IDependency>();

    mockEventAggregator.Setup(x => x.GetEvent<MonitoringRequestGenerated>())
            .Returns(mockMonitoringRequestedEvent.Object);

    Action<List<MonitoringRequest>> callbackMethod = null;

    mockMonitoringRequestedEvent
            .Setup(
                x => x.Subscribe(
                    It.IsAny<Action<List<MonitoringRequest>>>(),
                    It.IsAny<ThreadOption>(),
                    It.IsAny<bool>(),
                    It.IsAny<Predicate<List<MonitoringRequest>>>()))
            .Callback<Action<List<MonitoringRequest>>, ThreadOption, bool, Predicate<List<MonitoringRequest>>>(
                (a, t, b, p) => callbackMethod = a);

    var testFzrteMonitoringService = new FzrteMonitoringService(
            mockEventAggregator.Object, mockDependecy.Object);

    //use the actual  event aggregator to publish

    var mockMonitoringRequestEventPayload = new Mock<List<MonitoringRequest>>();
    mockEventAggregator.Object
            .GetEvent<MonitoringRequestGenerated>()
            .Publish(mockMonitoringRequestEventPayload.Object);

    mockMonitoringRequestedEvent.Verify(
            x => x.Subscribe(testFzrteMonitoringService.FilterEventType));
}
```

Though it may not work properly, but the main idea is there.

Comment: I am trying to test whether the handler for MonitoringRequestGenerated event is successfully invoked when such an event is published. Hence, mocking the eventaggregator. Since I do not have access to the Depedency source code, would modifying the constructor to look like: 
[ImportingConstructor]
public FzrteMonitoringService(
        IEventAggregator inEventAggregator, 
        IFzrteRequestsResponseHandler inHandler)

be alright? That would mean modifying all my classes to not use the dependency class. If I do it approach, perhaps IEventAggregator must also be resolved via IDependency.

Comment: @meon, yes, this way it should also work. The rule of thumb when using mocking in tests is to convert all dependencies in a class under test to those which you can easily mock.

Comment: Does the test make sense to you? I am testing whether the FzrteMonitoringService subscribes to the MonitoringRequestGenerated event. It may look like I am testing the event by mocking it, but I am really testing the interaction between the event (a dependency) and the service class. The service class is asking for the subscription, so it's interaction of the event and the service class via the subscription in the constructor.